# apex test class for web api call

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test, community, code-coverage

With Given below code Successfully implemented **HttpCalloutMock** . Method contains return type as **HTTPResponse** , i tried to run the test class for those methods that works perfect.Test method for **getpermissionresponse(String accesstoken)** covered all lines but **how to cover in test coverage of getpermission() ?** how to write test method that contains API calling method which is called. as i write Testmethod

in class i written methods like :-

```
public class facebook_API
{
  public static HttpResponse getpermissionresponse(String accesstoken) //covered in test class
  {
    Http http =new Http();
    String flagpermit ='true';
    HttpRequest req =new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint('https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token='+accesstoken);         
    req.setmethod('GET');
    return http.send(req);
  }
 public static void getpermission(String accesstoken) // how to cover in test coverage ? 
 {
    if((accesstoken!='')&&(accesstoken!=null))
    {
       HttpResponse res;
       res= facebook_API.getpermissionresponse(accesstoken);

       if(res.getStatusCode()==200)
       {
           list<facebookpermission.Data>  objpermission = new list<facebookpermission.Data>();
           MBT_SFFB.facebookpermission objfacebookuserpermission = new MBT_SFFB.facebookpermission();
           objfacebookuserpermission=MBT_SFFB.facebookpermission.parse(res.getBody());
       // insert statements for permissions.           
       }
    }
 }
 }
```

In Test class

```
 @isTest static void testgetpermissions()
{
   facebook_API.getpermission('EAACEdEose0dddfsdreZBSMh2KPTzhDN2Hrp2vZCnZAYhKyxEuMb5B1QJ3r2ZCaWcwgRUsz9D8bNa10XSuhkAPHYEiHUtRzeheubZAqWzetB5jsGBACsM9IuZB4qsQNteDXIjANtJZCSGIijNyk6LDxYlQHVTpkBYFX4ZD'); 
}
@isTest static void testgetpermission() {

  String json = '{'+
    '  \"data\": ['+
    '    {'+
    '      \"permission\": \"user_friends\",'+
    '      \"status\": \"granted\"'+
    '    },'+        
    '  ]'+
    '}';

    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponseGeneratorforpermission());
    HttpResponse res = facebook_API.getpermissionresponse('EAACEdEose0dddfsdreZBSMh2KPTzhDN2Hrp2vZCnZAYhKyxEuMb5B1QJ3r2ZCaWcwgRUsz9D8bNa10XSuhkAPHYEiHUtRzeheubZAqWzetB5jsGBACsM9IuZB4qsQNteDXIjANtJZCSGIijNyk6LDxYlQHVTpkBYFX4ZD');

    // Verify response received contains fake values
    String contentType = res.getHeader('Content-Type');
    System.assert(contentType == 'application/json');
    String actualValue = res.getBody();
    String expectedValue = json;
    System.assertEquals(actualValue, expectedValue);
    System.assertEquals(200, res.getStatusCode());
}
```

Mock Class

```
 @isTest
global class MockHttpResponseGeneratorforpermission implements HttpCalloutMock {
global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {

    // Optionally, only send a mock response for a specific endpoint
    // and method.
    String json = '{'+
'  \"data\": ['+
'    {'+
'      \"permission\": \"user_friends\",'+
'      \"status\": \"granted\"'+
'    },'+        
'  ]'+
'}';
    System.assertEquals('https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token=EAACEdEose0dddfsdreZBSMh2KPTzhDN2Hrp2vZCnZAYhKyxEuMb5B1QJ3r2ZCaWcwgRUsz9D8bNa10XSuhkAPHYEiHUtRzeheubZAqWzetB5jsGBACsM9IuZB4qsQNteDXIjANtJZCSGIijNyk6LDxYlQHVTpkBYFX4ZD', req.getEndpoint());
    System.assertEquals('GET', req.getMethod());
    // Create a fake response
    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.setBody(json);
    res.setStatusCode(200);
    return res;

}

}
```

Not Covering in coverage All lines after the below line :-

```
 if(res.getStatusCode()==200)
```

Comment: Can you post your mockapi callout class also?

Comment: Just use the mock class also in your `testgetpermissions` method.

Comment: Please look at Edited Question.  @Reshma

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this test method in your test class. You need to call method `getpermission` instead of `getpermissionresponse`. It will cover both the methods.

```
@isTest static void testgetpermission() {

    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponseGeneratorforpermission());

    facebook_API.getpermission('test');

    //Assert what you are doing after getting response
}
```

Comment: But my getpermission() return type must be void. i could not change its return type as HttpResponse

Comment: @InnodelSalesforce I have updated my code. You need to assert what you are doing with response you got after api callout.

Comment: It is calling one another Method that call API with Different ENDPOINT

Comment: @InnodelSalesforce you need set endpoint in mock class using `req.setEndpoint('your end point url');`

Comment: in case of test class :- how to write testcode for 2 API response using mock class ?? as i found in Docs there is one method of HttpCalloutMock Interface that is Respond() that returns only one HttpResponse at a time. My case is one API call success makes another API call in single method..